# lean method to replace text in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to replace texts on multiple pages by clicking a simple button. What is the leanest switch between two languages?

This only changes text in the first div. I need to have language change applied across the site.

```js
var text1 = document.getElementById('english');
var text2 = document.getElementById('swedish');

const swap = () => {
  if (text1.classList.contains("hidden")) { //if english contains class 'hidden'
    text1.classList.remove("hidden"); //remove hidden class from english
    text2.classList.add("hidden"); //add hidden class to swedish
  } else {
    text1.classList.add("hidden"); //add hidden class to english
    text2.classList.remove("hidden"); //remove hidden class from swedish
  }
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="swap()">Switch Text</button>

<div class="content">
  <div id="english">
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <p>English text</p>
  </div>
  <div id="swedish" class="hidden">
    <h1>Vällkommen</h1>
    <p>Svensk tekst</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. I had to fix many quotes (I assume you are on a mobile) and change the english to text1 and swedish to text2 in the functions to make it work

Comment: Please add to your snippet so we can see an example where it doesn’t work.

Comment: by "across the site" do you mean "this one entire html page" or "also every other page that might be part of this domain"?

Comment: across the whole website so user won't have to click again on next page to read his/her language.

Comment: thank you, mplungjan! I have to try if the lang selection stays when going to another page...

Comment: when moving to another page it goes back to default/English. how can I keep the lang selection for the user?

Answer (score 3):

1. Use `lang` as you are supposed to
2. Use classList.toggle

This script can be included on each page that has the lang set to either languages.

Change the lang to whatever you need. lang="en"/lang="sv" and change the script accordingly

Remove the comments `//` from the lines with localStorage and remove this line on your site: let savedLang = "se_SV";

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  //let savedLang = localStorage.getItem("lang") || "gb_EN";
  let savedLang = "se_SV";
  const btn = document.getElementById("swap");
  btn.dataset.lang = savedLang;

  btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    const tgt = e.target;
    let lang = tgt.dataset.lang;
    lang = lang === "gb_EN" ? "se_SV" : "gb_EN";
    tgt.dataset.lang = lang;
    // localStorage.setItem("lang",lang);
    const divs = document.querySelectorAll('div[lang]');
    divs.forEach(div => div.classList.toggle('hidden', div.lang === lang));
  })
  btn.click()
})
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="swap" data-lang="gb_EN">Switch Text</button>

<div class="content">
  <div lang="gb_EN">
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <p>English text</p>
  </div>
  <div lang="se_SV" class="hidden">
    <h1>Vällkommen</h1>
    <p>Svensk tekst</p>
  </div>
  <div lang="gb_EN">
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <p>English text</p>
  </div>
  <div lang="se_SV" class="hidden">
    <h1>Vällkommen</h1>
    <p>Svensk tekst</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: when moving to another page it goes back to default/English. how can I keep the lang selection for the user?

Comment: See update. Remove the comments `//` from the lines with localStorage and remove this line on your site: `let savedLang = "se_SV";`

Comment: I've tried but not working, even the language switch no longer works.

Comment: Your original post did not work at all. How can I know how you implemented what I did? Did you give an ID swap to your button, did you change the class to lang?

Comment: As you can see it works here, so implement what I changed to make your pages work too

Comment: I much appreciate your help, mplungjan! Haven't figured out yet what I'm doing wrong to not be able to save the lang selection to the next page but will keep trying.

Comment: I am sorry I cannot help you without seeing your code.

Answer (score 1):

[**Edit 2023/04/24**]

New insight: the 'leanest' way may be to use css to display the relevant content, where the body's `lang` attribute determines what is displayed. Here is a basic snippet working out that idea.

See also [Stackblitz snippet](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-vx4ykk?file=index.js) for usage with `localStorage`.

```js
loadLanguage( {
  switchBtn: document.querySelector(`#langSwitch`),
  first: `sv-SE`, 
  second: `en-GB`} );

function loadLanguage( { switchBtn, first, second } ) {
  let currentLang; // currentLang not necessary with localStorage
  const store = {
    get current() { return currentLang ?? first; },
    set current(value) { document.body.lang = currentLang = value; } };
  const toggleLang = lang => 
    store.current = lang ?? (store.current === first ? second : first);
  switchBtn.addEventListener(`click`, () => toggleLang());
  toggleLang(store.current);
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 1rem;
  font-family: system-ui, sans-serif;
}

body[lang="en-GB"] [lang="sv-SE"] {
  display: none;
}


body[lang="sv-SE"] [lang="en-GB"] {
  display: none;
}

body[lang="en-GB"] [lang="en-GB"] {
  display: initial;
}

body[lang="sv-SE"] [lang="sv-SE"] {
  display: initial;
}


body[lang="sv-SE"] #langSwitch:after {
  content: 'Switch to english';
  margin-left: 36px;
}

body[lang="en-GB"] #langSwitch:after {
  content: 'Byta till svenska';
  margin-left: 36px;
}

body[lang="sv-SE"] #langSwitch {
  background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/83/Flag_of_the_United_Kingdom_%283-5%29.svg) no-repeat 6px center;
  background-size: 32px;
}

body[lang="en-GB"] #langSwitch {
  background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4c/Flag_of_Sweden.svg) no-repeat 6px center;
  background-size: 32px;
  border: none;
}

#langSwitch {
  display: initial;
  border: none;
  padding: 8px;
  box-shadow: -2px -2px 4px #aaa inset;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

#langSwitch:hover {
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #aaa inset;
}

button {
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<button id="langSwitch" lang="sv-SE"></button>
<div lang="en-GB">
  <h1>Welcome</h1>
  <p>English text</p>
</div>

<div lang="sv-SE">
  <h1>Vällkommen</h1>
  <p>Svensk tekst</p>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry Kooilnc, didn't see your answer. how would you write the button part if only one button to switch between two languages? I don't get why the query selector is set like that.

Comment: @mplungjan: sure, in ES there are many ways to do the same thing. There's nothing wrong with your way, just wanted to present an alternative for more than two languages. I use event delegation by default, btw.

Comment: That is more interesting